# WatchKit text input suggestions without a WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I'm sending a push notification with a background `UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput` user notification action and would like to add custom response suggestions.

I realise that I can add suggested responses using `suggestionsForResponseToActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:inputLanguage:` on a `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`, but is it possible to provide suggestions from the iOS app without creating a WatchKit app?